# Cannot connect to mongodb using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am trying to set up with docker-compose 2 images: one related to a web app and the other one related to Mongo. Here is the file:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  mongohost:
   image: mongo
   restart: unless-stopped
   container_name: mongohost
   hostname: mongohost
   ports:
      - "27017:27017"
   volumes:
    - ./init-mongo.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh
   environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mydb
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MONGODB_INIT_DATABASE: mydb
      MONGODB_USER: mydb
      MONGODB_DATABASE: mydb
      MONGODB_PASS: mypass
   networks:
      - mongohost

  my-app:
    image: aws image
    container_name: my-app
    hostname: my-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:

      - MONGODB_NAME= mydb
      - MONGODB_URI= mongodb://mydb:mypass@mongohost:27017/mydb

    depends_on: 
      - mongohost
    networks:
      - mongohost  

networks:
  mongohost:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the init-mongo.sh:

```
mongosh -- "$MONGODB_DATABASE" <<EOF
var user = '$MONGODB_USER';
var passwd = '$MONGODB_PASS';
var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
admin.auth(user, passwd);
db.createUser({user: user, pwd: passwd, roles: ["readWrite"]});
EOF
```

The issue is that when I use the command docker-compose up only Mongo instance gets started, instead my app prompts this error message:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
```

It looks like it tries to connect to localhost but it should address the MongoDB on the docker container that is set up along with it. How can I override it? The application properties file gives me only these 2 variables that can be overridden:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=${MONGODB_NAME}
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGODB_URI}
```

Comment: Can you check that the application uses the correct connection string? Could also be related to the configuration of the app container instead of docker-compose.

Comment: I guess you like to create the user in `admin` database, thus better use `admin.createUser(...)`, otherwise it will be created in `mydb` database.

Comment: I need the user related to the mydb, by the way i don't think user is involved in the connection issue. The app works on openshift in more environment so the problem is related to the containers .